# Reliability and flaws with GitHub's 'Dependabot: Automated security fixes'

Tags: security, github, dependencies, package

I want to learn from others about whether GitHub's 'Dependabot: Automated security fixes' is a secure reliable solution to security issues.

The one and only time GitHub flagged a security issue it was also for outdated dependencies.
At that time I pulled from the repository, manually updated them, and then pushed them back up.
To date I have not found on Stack Overflow any comment directly addressing my question. 
Please correct me if I am wrong.

How safe are the automated fixes? Can we blindly rely on them? Should I use them with any sort of caution?

[Screenshot including the green 'Create automated security fix' button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RYHe.png).

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Is there a specific concern you could articulate?

Comment: Thanks for that question - I thought I was clear with the original post. 
I'll try to modify the original post to be more clear. 
I wanted to know how safe it was to use the automated security fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Dependabot will notify you about security issues known for certain dependencies.

The only drawback could be:

- The new dependency bring other issues.
- It does not guarantee that the upgrade won't provoke side effects, such as bugs introduced by an unexpected behavior of the dependency in your project.

So don't forget to test the upgrade on your project whether through automated ones or manually.